# how to correct datetime format using Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime-format

I want to ask a simple question about datatime format in matlab.
I know "HH:MM:SS:SSS"is like "Hour:Minute:Second:MillisSecond".What if I just need "MM:SS:SSS". Is this possible in matlab? 
Can I use the following code in my program?

```
dt = datestr(A,'MM:SS:SSS')
```

Thanks. 
What I am trying to do is add a timestamp at each line of my output txt. 
The first line is "00：00：000"
The second line is "00：00：100"

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but there's no `SSSS` for `MillisSecond` with datetime format in Matlab. You should read more carefully [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#inputarg_formatOut).

In case you need MillisSecond, you have to use `FFF`, and you can only get MillisSecond in 3 digits:

```
datestr(rem(now, 1), 'MM:SS:FFF');
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. The format is "MM:SS.FFF". What I am trying to do is add a timestamp at each line of my output txt.

Comment: The first line is "00:00:000". The second line is "00:00:100". like this.

Comment: i'm sorry, but what is actually your question? edit your question and explain more carefully what you really wanted ...